# Update IIS6 "IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions" from ASP web page

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6, ip-address

I receive a number of error reports about attempted hacks that try to access a specific file (which I don't use). I usually block the IP address manually using the "IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions" in IIS6. Is it possible to add an entry to this list from an ASP page? That way I could set the page so that it automatically blocks the IP address of whoever tries to access it, that is, hackers. I could simply remove the file, but I would like to stop them from attempting something else, something that would go undetected.

Thanks!

Comment: Just looking at some of the other posts you've included, is this definitely [tag:asp-classic], or is it [tag:asp.net]?

Comment: @Paul yes, because the file that they are trying to access is io.asp. I want to replace it one version that blocks them.

Comment: Since I could not get an answer, I have go for a different approach for which I asked a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
<% 
' create an array with a list of ip addresses you want blocked:
blocked=Array("127.0.0.1","::1","192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2","192.168.1.3")
' filter the array, using the ip address of the current visitor:
result=Filter(blocked, Request.Servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR"))
' if the users address is in the list, response.end will block the visitor
if UBound(result) > 0 Then Response.end 
%>
```

Note this is classic asp, not asp.net, as per your tag.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by Kul-Tigin; the filter function will not work. We could change the approach to a simple for-loop:

```
dim i, current_address, blacklist
blacklist=Array("127.0.0.1","::1","192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2","192.168.1.3")
current_address = Request.Servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
for i = Lbound(blacklist) to Ubound(blacklist)
    if current_address = blacklist(i) then response.end
next 'i
```

Erik

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question. All it does, is stop the page from loading if the IP address is in a pre-defined list. What I want to do is add the IP address of someone trying to access a particular file to the list of blocked IP addresses in IIS6. I could add it to a database, and use your approach, but I want to avoid that because I don't want to query a database for every page load of every page. I want to block the IP from all the site altogather. And I neeed it classic ASP because the targeted file in question is a ASP file (although I could redirect to a .net file).

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I misunderstood. IIS6 seems to be scriptable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163534/how-can-you-set-iis6-settings-via-the-command-line but you'll have to execute this script with a user that has enough rights to do so. In other words, you'll have to run your ASP IIS user with a lot of rights, that might be a security risk of its own...

Comment: @RicoSuave It must be `if UBound(result) > -1 Then`, but it's not the point, there's another big problem with your code. You should not use `Filter` such purposes. Because it works like a `StartsWith` operator so it's not suitable for that. If the `blocked` contains `192.168.1.101`, `192.168.1.10` will be banned too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Kul-Tigin I have edited the answer. Also @Osprey; you could use this solution and store the blacklist in an application scope variable. Put the code in an include on every page you want to protect and add an IP address to the array in the application scope when you detect someone you want to block. Only thing is tha application scope is cleared when you restart IIS/the server.